# What are the verses in Bhagavad-Gita that support Advaita?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

Which verses in Bhagavad-Gita Support Advaitic Doctrine ?

Comment: The Gita supports all the philosophical schools. It does not support one exclusively. See Gita 9.15 and Gita 7.21.

Comment: Sir I know Gita supports all Philosphies. Please help me by giving more Advaitic verses from Gita @SwamiVishwananda

Comment: There are many verses. You can check this for a start - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/45455/23407  Listing all the verses will make the answer very long.

Comment: I have upvoted and noted them. Can you help more ? @alsoran

Comment: Sir, please pick up the commentaries of Sri Adi Sankaracharya and Sri Madhusudhana Saraswati. Both are available in English translation.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 3 verses that have strong Advaita flavor.

> As a kindled fire reduces all fuel to ashes, so, Arjuna! does **the fire
> of knowledge** reduce all works to ashes.

**Gita 4.37**

> All these (four) are noble; **but the knower, I deem to be My very Self**;
> for, with an integrated self, he has resorted to Me alone, the goal
> without parallel.

**Gita 7.18**

> Moved by compassion for those (devotees) and dwelling in their mental
> states, with **the lustrous flame of knowledge**, I destroy the darkness
> of ignorance.

**Gita 10.11**

Answer (score 0):

> BG 6.30: For those who see me everywhere and see all things in me, I am never lost, nor are they ever lost to me.

> BG 9.7-8: At the end of one kalp, all living beings merge into My primordial material energy. At the beginning of the next creation, O son of Kunti, **I manifest them again**. Presiding over My material energy, I generate these myriad forms again and again, in accordance with the force of their natures.

> BG 9.4: This entire cosmic manifestation is pervaded by Me in My unmanifest form. All living beings dwell in Me, but I do not dwell in them

> BG 9.10: Working under **My direction, this material energy brings into being all animate and inanimate forms**, O son of Kunti. For this reason, the material world undergoes the changes (of creation, maintenance, and dissolution).

> BG 9.15: Others, engaging in the yajña of cultivating knowledge, worship Me by many methods. **Some see Me as undifferentiated oneness** that is non-different from them, while others see Me as separate from them. Still others worship Me in the infinite manifestations of My cosmic form.

> BG 9.18: I am the Supreme Goal of all living beings, and I am also their Sustainer, Master, Witness, Abode, Shelter, and Friend. I am the Origin, End, **and Resting Place of creation**; I am the Storehouse and Eternal Seed.

Comment: I asked Advatic verses not Dvaitha
Except 9.15 rest all dont suit. Or may be that I amnt able to grasp

Answer (score 0):

O Arjun, I am seated in the heart of all living entities. I am the beginning, middle, and end of all beings -
BG 10.20

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Hinduism SE. You can elaborate your answer on how it support Advaita.